# Form not submitted because field type

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm using html and javascript.
I notice after I change the field type from number to text, the form not submitted anymore.
Also, there is no error in the console.
any advice.

Comment: Help us help you - share the code you have so far

Comment: If you're wanting help, you should use CodePen or something to show us an example of your code.

Need to show us what you've tried, what isn't working, and let us replicate the issue or we're going to be pretty unable to help you.

Comment: @Mureinik the code added.

Comment: @IDI how do you submit the form is there no button inside the form?

Comment: Could you please also share your javascript?

Comment: @IDI small tip sometimes you do not see such error in the console but you can see it in network tab where there are further details on why the form was not being submitted

Comment: Without providing a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, it is hard for anyone to help troubleshoot this without guessing

Comment: Can you please keep the code visible?